# Putting a dataset that contains - and + into an list

Tags: javascript, numeric

Iam trying to solve the advent challange and i have been givning a dataset with alot of numbers that contain - and + fx:

-1
+2
-4

The challange is that: What is the first frequency your device reaches twice?

So I came up with a solution that split up my data set into an matrix, so I can do the calculation on that.

However the first step in this solution is to get my dataset into a list so they loop like this:

```
let frequency = [[-1,2,-3],
                 [2,-1,3]]
```

How can this be done with javascript? Right now iam only getting the sum of all the numbers...

I hope somebody can help a coding elf solve this christmas problem!

Comment: How are the example you provided and the `frequency` array related?

Comment: Because I need to split the values into an array.

Comment: But how did you get the `frequency` array out of `"-1 +2 -4"`? Where did you get `3`, and where did `-4` go, and why are there 6 elements in `frequecy` but only 3 in `"-1 +2 -4"`?

Comment: Provide a complete example, with an example input and its desired output and preferably the code you've tried so far.

Comment: The puzzle provides a long list of numbers. The numbers I provided are just random numbers so simulate my problem. Basicly I need to take thoese numbers and convert them into an array.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a string of numbers separated by spaces into an array of numbers, you can do this:

```
let str = "+3 -1 2 -1 +4 -5"; // example input;

const arr = str.split(' ');
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arr[i] = parseFloat(arr[i]);
```

After that, `arr` will be `[3, -1, 2, -1, 4, -5]`.

Now, if you want to count the number each item appears in array, you can do this:

```
const freq = {};
for (const item of arr) {
  freq[item] = ++freq[item] || 1;
}
```

This will create an object named `freq` which will be: `{ 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, "-1": 2, "-5": 1 }`.